# gitlab - push file to gitlab with scp command

Tags: gitlab

I have upladed id_rsa.pub to gitlab.com and try to use below command push file to gitlab.com:

```
scp README.md git@gitlab.com:/home/username/project/README.md
```

But it says:

```
GitLab: Disallowed command
```

Can I use scp push file to my project folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute commands from the session you created. The point of Gitlab is to have git development environment, so you want to do the following:

- Clone the repo into a local folder.
- Edit the file README.md
- Git add . (dot adds all the files).
- Git commit -m "Your commit message".
- Git push.

You can get the cloning url from the web ui @ gitlab.

You should do `git clone git@gitlab.com:repo/path`